# Saved over word document with blank document. Can I recover the old version?

Tags: microsoft-word, macbook-air

I had written up my assessment and saved it. However, at some point I have saved over it with just my heading title. Can I recover my original document? I am using the current word and a MacBook Air. 
I know I might be pushing my luck with this one.

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything yet? It's helpful for you to tell us what you've tried just so that we can better suggest things that might work

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to recover your file using a recovery tool.
My favorite is [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).  It is also available for Mac.
You best use an external disk to recover to.

However, the time you'll spent in possibly recovering the file may outweigh the time you need to redo your work.

Also the more you work with the disk on which the file you wish to recover is located, the less likely it is you may recoverit.

Finally, if you saved your file in a location synchronised to a cloud, it may be that the cloud has some older versions of your file.  When so, go to your cloud management interface and see if you can recover an older version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is MAYBE.  This actually happened to my niece.  She was working on a paper and accidentally deleted it.  When a file is deleted on a hard drive there are only a few bytes that are changed in order to give the space back to the drive.  If you flip those bytes back you can "undelete" the file.  The trick is this.  As long as other files have not been written in that part of the drive you can recover your file.  How then do you undelete it?

http://www.iskysoft.us/data-recovery-mac/recuva-for-mac.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjwvOC5BRCb_8yNmZ_ls9IBEiQACTz8vtF1djxKLYf0jwM8DCLcnh__OkzH6geHMz2GJMMD3PsaAjXl8P8HAQ

Use this.  This allows you to undelete files.  Now the trick here is to find the right file to undelete.  Word often makes temporary files save automatically.  This is how I got my niece's paper back.  If you can sort by modified date once you get in the tool, chances are your file will float closer to the top since it was modified last.